# Example of a discrete random variable using the measure-theoretic definition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

**Context**

I'm trying to wrap my head around the measure-theoretic definition of a random variable. I put forward this example in the hopes that someone can verify that my understanding is correct, or else indicate how it is incorrect.

I have done a non-exhaustive search on this site. I have found [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e10NM.jpg) helpful, but it still does not give me full comprehension.

**Problem**

In the figure below, I offer a circular wheel with uniform density. The experiment is to spin the wheel and record what color is aligned with the rightmost vertice of the black triangle.

[image: An experiment consists of spinning the wheel and seeing what color aligns with the triangle]

By $\Omega$, I denote the sample space, which I enumerate with three outcomes as
$$\Omega = \left\{\text{red}, \text{blue}, \text{green} \right\}.$$

By $\mathcal{F}$, I denote the $\sigma$-algebra, which I enumerate with $2^3$ events as
$$\mathcal{F} = \left\{\varnothing, \left\{\text{red}\right\}, \left\{\text{blue}\right\}, \left\{\text{green}\right\}, \left\{\text{red}, \text{green}\right\}, \left\{\text{red}, \text{blue}\right\}, \left\{\text{green}, \text{blue}\right\}, \left\{\text{red}, \text{green}, \text{blue}\right\}  \right\}.$$

By $P$, I denote the probability measure, which I enumerate
\begin{align}
P(\varnothing) 
&= 
0,
\\
P(\left\{\text{red}\right\}) 
&= 
1/6,
\\
P(\left\{\text{blue}\right\}) 
&= 
3/6,
\\
P(\left\{\text{green}\right\}) 
&= 
2/6,
\\
P(\left\{\text{red}, \text{blue}\right\}) 
&= 
4/6,
\\
P(\left\{\text{red}, \text{green}\right\}) 
&= 
3/6,
\\
P(\left\{\text{green}, \text{blue}\right\}) 
&= 
5/6,~\text{and}
\\
P(\left\{\text{red}, \text{green}, \text{blue}\right\} ) 
&= 
6/6.
\end{align}

By the triplet $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},P)$, I denote the probability space.

By $E$, I denote the set  $\left\{1,2,3\right\}.$

By $\mathcal{E}$, I denote a $\sigma$-algebra that I give as
$$\mathcal{E} = \left\{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{2\},\{1,3\},\{3\},\{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\}\right\}.$$

By the tuple $(E ,{\mathcal {E}})$, I denote the measurable space.

By the measurable function $ X\colon \Omega \to E$, I denote an $(E,{\mathcal {E}})$-valued random variable that I define as
\begin{align}
X(\omega) = 
\begin{cases}
1,&~\text{if}~\omega = \text{red};
\\
2,&~\text{if}~\omega = \text{blue};~\text{or}
\\
3,&~\text{if}~\omega = \text{green}.
\end{cases}
\end{align}

For every subset $B\in {\mathcal {E}}$, I denote its preimage as $X^{-1}(B)$, where $X^{-1}(B)=\{\omega :X(\omega )\in B\} $.

I want to check that for every subset in $\mathcal {E} $, its preimage $X^{-1}(B)$ is in $\mathcal {F}$.

\begin{align}
X^{-1}(\varnothing) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \varnothing\} = \varnothing 
\\
X^{-1}(\{1\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{1\}\} = \{\text{red} \}
\\
X^{-1}(\{2\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{2\}\} = \{\text{blue} \}
\\
X^{-1}(\{3\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{3\}\} = \{\text{green} \}
\\
X^{-1}(\{1,2\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{1,2\}\} = \{\text{red},\text{blue}\} 
\\
X^{-1}(\{1,3\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{1,3\}\} = \{\text{red},\text{green} \}
\\
X^{-1}(\{2,3\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{2,3\}\} = \{\text{blue},\text{green} \}
\\
X^{-1}(\{1,2,3\}) 
&= \{\omega : X(\omega)\in \{1,2,3\}\} = \{\text{red},\text{blue},\text{green} \}
\end{align}

**Biibliography**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e10NM.jpg) [Intuitively, how should I think of Measurable Functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125122/intuitively-how-should-i-think-of-measurable-functions)

Comment: Using $\emptyset$ to denote a wheel stop between two colors is a bad choice of notation. If you want to include this outcome in $\Omega$, then $\mathcal{F}$ would contain $2^4$ elements.

Comment: You are concerned about definition of random variable but unfortunately I cannot find any random variable in your question. Are you thinking of a function $\Omega\to E$ that e.g. sends "red" to $1$, "blue" to $2$ and "green" to $3$ maybe? The probability space that you created looks okay to me.

Comment: $X^{-1}(\{1\})=\{\text{red}\}$ (not $\cdots=\text{red}$). Same story for $X^{-1}(\{2\})$ and $X^{-1}(\{3\})$. Further things are okay I think.

Comment: @drhab. noted and modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that my example is verified as correct. Since I could not find a lucid example on-line, I am leaving this question up for pedagogical purposes.